# why is a ruby app videos not previewing on iphone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iphone, ruby, video

i have a ruby on rails app, front end is html, css and javascript. The videos show a preview on Android phone browsers, but will show a white or black screen as shown on the right on iphone. how do i fix this?
this happens on both browsers i tested on safari and chrome

```
    <div class="video"> 
    <video style="" controls="controls" src="/rails/active_storage/myvideo.mp4"></video> 
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: So, what's the code? what browsers did you try? maybe it's a Safari error/feature, doesn't look like an error on rails' side.

Comment: i think its an ios software setting somewhere

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with how the video is encoded — if it's encoded as VP9 in an MP4 container, it won't play on an iOS device. If you have the source video you can use ffmpeg to transcode it as an H.265 video — then it should play on both devices.